# Bash shell script to get the last sentence after slash

Tags: bash

I am super new with Bash and want to write a shell script. I want to call on the shell script like this: `./test.sh /root/data/test/something.txt` and then the script will do a regular expression on the argument and assign the filename to a variable (`$filename`). Which means it need to go trough all the / until the last one or something like that.

I know I can use $1 in order to get the whole argument but how to do the regex is far beyond my knowledge. I would appreciate the help a lot!

Comment: @Inian I have seen that post, I could however not figure it out. Could you please help?

Comment: If the argument `/root/data/test/something.txt` is received as `$1` inside your script then just do `filname="${1##*/}"`, here `$1` is the first positional argument passed to your script

Comment: @Inian Great, many thanks, how would this work if the path sometimes change? Shorter or longer? :)

Comment: See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe on various string manipulation techniques `bash` provides